# undefined method `namespace' for main:Object (NoMethodError) when running rails server after adding pg_dump

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pg-dump

After adding pg_dump I get this error when running the rails server:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    50: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    49: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    48: from /home/fajweh/dumptest/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    47: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    46: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    45: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    44: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    43: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    42: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    41: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    40: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    39: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    38: from /home/fajweh/dumptest/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    37: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
    36: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
    35: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
    34: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    33: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    32: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    31: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    30: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    29: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    28: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    27: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    26: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    25: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    24: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    23: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `perform'
    22: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `tap'
    21: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:141:in `block in perform'
    20: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
    19: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
    18: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
    17: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    16: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    15: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    14: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    13: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    12: from /home/fajweh/dumptest/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
    11: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
    10: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
     9: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
     8: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
     7: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
     6: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
     5: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
     4: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     3: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
     2: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     1: from /home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/home/fajweh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pg_dump-0.5.0/lib/pg_dump.rb:3:in `<main>': undefined method `namespace' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

I replicated this with a fresh rails app.

Comment: The problem with this (unmaintained) gem is it's not following the standard Rails file naming/organization. The rake task: `rake pg:dump` is contained in a `.rb` file. I don't believe that Rails can accept this. It should be a `.rake` file, within the `lib/tasks` directory. You don't need the gem as @JP Silvashy notes below.

Answer (score 0):

This gem appears to be not very well maintained: https://github.com/ziyouchutuwenwu/pg_dump

What are you trying to do? You can dump your DB with the postgres commands directly, you dont need a gem:

```
pg_dump mydb > db.sql
```

Comment: I tried running db:structure:dump on app engine and got an error message telling to make sure pg_dump is installed. But it's not possible to install things on app engine in an obvious way, like with apt or dnf, so I tried using the gem file.

Comment: So you want to dump your database into your running app engine instance? I'm not sure you can do that for a number of reasons. You should not be running `db:structure:dump` on your running instance, you can do this locally in development and commit/deploy your schema. Additionally, this gem runs the pg_dump command just like i mentioned, although it seems to help construct the arguments, but thats it see this line: https://github.com/ziyouchutuwenwu/pg_dump/blob/master/lib/pg_dump.rb#L10

Comment: I just tried to get the schema. I solved it by exporting the database.